# How to send a code error in the catch block Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, try-catch

I have problem in the try/catch block here's the code :

```
catch((err) => {
winston.error(new Date() +' : '+req.originalUrl +' : '+`${id}`+' : '+err);
res.status(500);
})
```

when the request failed, the catch block called the winston print the error in the console, but the problem the request does not stopped, I tried to send a 500 code it doesn't work(here's a screenshot of postman when catch block is called).

[image]

My question now is, How I can send 500 code error, and stop the request process at the same time.?

Comment: What web framework do you use? Do you use any? Express for example?

Comment: yes, I'm using Express,

Comment: Could you show the code before the catch?

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
res.sendStatus(500);
```

instead of

```
res.status(500);
```

The latter only sets the `statusCode` property of the Response but it's not sending anything

Comment: that give an error :Error: Response validation failed: invalid content type (text/plain).  These are valid: application/json
    at Object.module.exports.validateContentType

Comment: It's hard to say what's going on. Could you post more lines of the stack trace or tell where the error comes from? Is it caused by your code or by some external dependency?

Comment: Error: Response validation failed: invalid content type (text/plain).  These are valid: application/json
    at Object.module.exports.validateContentType (node_modules\swagger-tools\lib\validators.js:234:11)
    at ServerResponse.res.end (node_modules\swagger-tools\middleware\swagger-validator.js:232:20)
    at ServerResponse.send (node_modules\express\lib\response.js:221:10)
    at ServerResponse.sendStatus (node_modules\express\lib\response.js:359:15)
    at sendStatus (src\api\controllers/clients.js:336:9)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

Comment: Also, do you have any Swagger validation schemas or something?